# How to display only few intervals in x-axis while having more data using line jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

I created a linechart using jfreechart and my dataset is as follows...

```
 Date d = s.getUpdateDate();
 String date = DATE_FORMAT.format(d);
 lineDataset.addValue(s.getCount(), s.getAutomationName(), date);
```

I got a chart with count values and wrt grouping of date and automationName.

I want to display data for 365 days(which means 365 dates) in X-axis and in that case once the chart is generated i dont want all the dates to be displayed in the X-axis. In that case i need only 12 intervals to be displayed one for each month.

I need the interval to get modified so that all dates should not be displayed in x-axis.

Looking forward for your suggestions :)
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you've got and what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I have domain axis intervals for all 365 days.  It is not possible all of them in the chart. So I wanted to display only few intervals like 1 per month resulting in 12 intervals displaying in domain axis.

I came to know about timeseries chart and it automatically does it based upon chart width.
Thanks moeTi.